# DOCTYPE declaration removes my background image

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have a html document where i would like to have an image as a background. For the next example eveything works great:

```
<html><head></head><body><div id="principal"></div></body></html>
```

css:

```
#principal 
{
    background: url(../Img/org/world.png) no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

but if i rewrite the html file to :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div id="principal"></div></body></html>
```

the image from css ( background: url(../Img/org/world.png) no-repeat; ) is not displayed anymore. Why?

Comment: There is no good reason. Did you try a hard refresh (ctrl + f5)?

Comment: Which browser and, if IE, which version?

Comment: You forgot to include the CSS file...?

Comment: @Juhana you have got to be kidding me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your style-sheet:

```
html,body {width:100%;height:100%;}
```

The DIV you set to 100% doesn't have any reference to what it should set 100% of. Telling the browser that the document is to fill 100% of what is available creates a reference for the div element.

A fiddle to fiddle around with:
http://jsfiddle.net/UJsRW/

Answer (score 0):

The second html tag should be after the head tag.
Then tell the body and html to be 100% height & width in your css.

Here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/dbb67/2/

```
body, html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#principal {
display:block;
position:relative;
background: url(http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs42/i/2009/154/4/d/fantasy_landscape_bg_9_by_joannastar_stock.jpg) no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```